# Downloading JUST g++ binary

Tags: g++

This question may seem stupid to you guys, but I am in a situation where I have no access to command line, and I need a version of g++ on my computer so I can compile my c++ code.

I looked on the GNU repository, and I have NO idea how to build and also install the environment.

Where can I simply just download the 'g++' file, without going through all these trouble?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is not clear what you ask for. Downloading a program is not difficult, and you certainly need to know how to do it prior to start programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where can I simply just download the 'g++' file, without going through all these trouble?

Downloading the `g++` file will not do you any good: the GNU C++ compiler distribution consists of several hundreds of files. The `g++` is just the compiler front end, you'll also need `cc1plus` (the actual compiler), header files and libraries.